# Xpath to get text of all node but the one with specific tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

So, I got this type of html schema:

```
<table id="proposal-details" class="details">

                        <tbody><tr>
                            <th>
                                Application type:
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                P
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Proposed development
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                Prune 1 x Eucalyptus
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Date received:
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                06 Feb 2015
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Registration date:
                                <br>
                                (Statutory start date)
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                06 Feb 2015
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I've got the xpath to capture all the **th**; this goes well all the way to the last **th** with text *Registration date:* where I actually do not need the **br** text to be selected.

I got a work around to this, the problem is with this xpath,

```
len(response.xpath("//table//tr//th[not(.//br)]/text()").extract())
```

the whole **th** tag is overlooked.
Any suggestion?

this is the output I get:

```
[u' Application type: ',
 u' Proposed development ',
 u' Date received: ']
```

where I actually need the *Registration date:* without the *(Statutory start date)* in the list.

Comment: What exactly is the output you expect? Please show it as code, rather than explaining it in prose, and show more Python so that people can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to get the text of all `th` elements but ignore the text after the `<br>`. If that's the case, the following XPath

```
//table//tr//th/text()[not(preceding-sibling::br)]
```

when applied to your input has the result

```
Application type:
Proposed development
Date received:
Registration date:
```

The XPath you used just ignores every `th` having a child `br`:

```
th[not(.//br)]
```

while `th/text()[not(preceding-sibling::br)]` retrieves all text elements of `th` that don't have a preceding sibling `br`.